# Looking for a Python procedure to extract table information from image

Tags: python, machine-learning, tabular, information-extraction

We have paper invoices coming in, which are in paper format. We take images of these invoices, and wish to extract the information contained within the cells of the tabular region(s), and export them as CSV or similar.

The tables include multiple columns, and the cells contain numbers and words.

I have been searching around for ML-based Python procedures to have this performed, expecting this to be a relatively straightforward task (or maybe I'm mistaken), yet not much luck in coming across a procedure.

I can detect the horizontal and vertical lines, and combine them to locate the cells. But retrieving the information contained within the cells seems to be problematic.

Could I please get help?

I followed one procedure from [this reference](https://analyticsindiamag.com/how-to-use-opencv-to-extract-information-from-table-images/), yet came across an error with "bitnot":

```
import pytesseract
extract=[]
for i in range(len(order)):
    for j in range(len(order[i])):
        inside=''
        if(len(order[i][j])==0):
            extract.append(' ')
        else:
            for k in range(len(order[i][j])):
                side1,side2,width,height = order[i][j][k][0],order[i][j][k][1], order[i][j][k][2],order[i][j][k][3]
                final_extract = bitnot[side2:side2+h, side1:side1+width]
                final_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (2, 1))
                get_border = cv2.copyMakeBorder(final_extract,2,2,2,2, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,value=[255,255])
                resize = cv2.resize(get_border, None, fx=2, fy=2, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
                dil = cv2.dilate(resize, final_kernel,iterations=1)
                ero = cv2.erode(dil, final_kernel,iterations=2)
                ocr = pytesseract.image_to_string(ero)
                if(len(ocr)==0):
                    ocr = pytesseract.image_to_string(ero, config='--psm 3')
                inside = inside +" "+ ocr
            extract.append(inside)

a = np.array(extract)
dataset = pd.DataFrame(a.reshape(len(hor), total))
dataset.to_excel("output1.xlsx")
```

The error I get is this:

```
final_extract = bitnot[side2:side2+h, side1:side1+width]
NameError: name 'bitnot' is not defined`
```

Comment: Do you have a sample image?